# Crop image based on element dimensions

Tags: javascript

As the title says I am trying to crop an image. I take a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU407.png) of the visible area of my tab (using a method from Google Chrome extension). Then I use [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) to get the dimensions of the following [element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ8x8.png). The dimensions of my element are `bottom: 253.390625, height: 125, left: 820, right: 1020, top: 128.390625, width: 200`. My problem is getting the element dimensions to align with my screenshot. My results look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlV2R.png. As you can see I am not even close to the element I cam trying to crop. Why is this happening?

**Code**

```
// here we create a new image
function createImage(dataURL) {
    // elements dimensions
    var element = elementDimensions();
    // labels
    var elementWidth = element.width;
    var elementHeight = element.height;
    // create a canvas
    var canvas = createCanvas(elementWidth, elementHeight);
    // get the context of your canvas
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // create a new image object
    var croppedImage = new Image();

    croppedImage.onload = function() {
        // cropping
        context.drawImage(croppedImage, element.x, element.y, elementWidth, elementHeight, 0, 0, elementWidth, elementHeight);
        // show results
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
    };
    croppedImage.src = dataURL; // screenshot (full image)
}

// creates a canvas element
function createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    // size of canvas in pixels
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    return canvas;
}

// get element dimensions
function elementDimensions() {
    // element dimensions
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName("itemlist")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    return {
        x: element.left,
        y: element.top,
        width: element.width,
        height: element.height
    };
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `getBoundingClientRect` start from the top of the page, not the top of the visible space?

Comment: @abiessu From what I understand yes. top left at (0, 0).

Comment: I can't tell from your image; is your scroll position in the page at the top also?

Comment: Yes I'm at (0,0) I haven't scrolled at all.